# [karate][standalone v0.9.1] Error : could not find or read file: file:xxx/yyy/zzz/./karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I am only using the latest standalone karate jar to test my API on a docker image configured with JRE and I don't have any Java code.

This is what i have currently with the new version :

> 09:30:37.333 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.netty.Main - Karate
>   version: 0.9.1 09:30:37.489 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner -
>   Karate version: 0.9.1 09:30:38.067 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] WARN 
>   com.intuit.karate - skipping bootstrap configuration: could not find
>   or read file: file:xxx/yyy/zzz/./karate-config.js

Here we can see it didn't find my karate-config.js file

This is what i have with the v0.9.0 :

> 09:48:35.829 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.netty.Main - Karate
>   version: 0.9.0 09:48:35.971 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner -
>   Karate version: 0.9.0 09:48:36.559 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO 
>   com.intuit.karate - karate.env selected environment was: preprod

Here we can see it found my karate-config.js file

Did something change on 0.9.1 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes something changed :( - we've been trying to fix this file resolution problem for a while. It would be great if you help us reproduce this. Since you don't use Java, can you create a zip file of the directory structure that can replicate this problem.

As a workaround, please try setting the location to the config file as per the docs:

```
-Dkarate.config.dir=xxx/yyy/zzz
```

EDIT - this is fixed and you need to re-download the binary (same version) from here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.9.1

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it works with

> -Dkarate.config.dir=xxx/yyy/zzz

But only on this case :

> -Dkarate.config.dir="./"

I have reproduced the error on a simplified environment, you can download this file :
[Karate-Test Zip File](https://1fichier.com/?cnuw07y60pzywv3jmv8v)

You just have then  to execute the different .sh and see what is happening.

On the file karate-0.9.1/karate-0.9.1.sh , you have to read the comment, it works on a specific case, and it doesn't on another.

EDIT : 
Another thing,

even on the 0.9.0 version case, it doesn't work when i'm not on the same directory
than the script during the execution of the script

for instance, if i'm not on the same directory, this command is not working :

> ./karate-0.9.0/karate-0.9.0.sh
>
> 13:01:25.764 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.netty.Main - Karate
>   version: 0.9.0 13:01:25.830 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner -
>   Karate version: 0.9.0 13:01:26.402 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] WARN 
>   com.intuit.karate - skipping bootstrap configuration: could not find
>   or read file: classpath:karate-config.js

while this one is if i'm on the same directory :

> ./karate-0.9.0.sh 13:03:54.831 [main] INFO 
>   com.intuit.karate.netty.Main - Karate version: 0.9.0 13:03:54.905
>   [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - Karate version: 0.9.0
>   13:03:55.421 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate -
>   baseUrl selected was: https://petstore.swagger.io

Comment: fixed. I decided to re-upload the binary. can you please re-download from here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.9.1